# Ingresar datos a una DB en Sqlite usando Python y Tkinter

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite, tkinter

Buen dia!!! 
Soy super novato en el lenguaje Python, estoy haciendo un programa que sera una base de datos para laboratorio con una interfaz grafica, donde quiero ingresar el nombre de paciente y sus datos, al momento de ingresarlos me arroja este error:

File "laboratorio.py", line 136, in add_pac
    if self.add_pac():
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Las lineas "File "laboratorio.py", line 136, in add_pac; if self.add_pac():" aparecen varias veces y al final termina con el runtimeerror

mi pregunta es a que se refiere ese error y como lo puedo eliminar porque no he encontrado una manera de solucionarlo, comparto mi codigo para ver si ustedes encuentran el problema.
Muchas gracias!!!!

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
 from Tkinter import *
 import ttk
 import Tkinter as tk
 import sqlite3 # modulo de conexion con sqlite3 


class Product:
#conexion con la base de datos
db_lab = 'laboratorio.db'

def __init__(self, window):
    self.wind = window
    self.wind.title('Sistema de control')
    self.wind.geometry('1080x720')

    #creando el contenedor
    frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Elegir una de las siguientes opciones: ')
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)
    frame.configure(background = 'gray')
    #ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Save Product', command = self.add_product).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2)
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Registro de paciente', command = self.ventana_paciente).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2, pady = 10, sticky = W)
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Captura de analisis').grid(row = 4, columnspan = 2, pady = 10, sticky = W)
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Entrega de resultados').grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2, pady = 10, sticky = W)

def ventana_paciente(self):
    self.wind_pac = tk.Toplevel()
    self.wind_pac.title = ('Registro del paciente')
    self.wind_pac.configure(background = 'gray')
    self.wind_pac.geometry('1200x720')
    self.wind_pac.resizable(False, False)

    # Aniadimos el frame (Caja) donde se va a incluir el Treeview

    self.wind_pac1 = ttk.Frame(self.wind_pac)
    self.wind_pac1.grid(row=11, column=0)          

    #Apellido Paterno
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Apellido Paterno: ', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    a_paterno = Entry(self.wind_pac, width = 20)
    a_paterno.focus()
    a_paterno.grid(row = 1, column = 2)


    #Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = name), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 2)

    #Apellido Materno
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Apellido Materno', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 10)
    a_materno = Entry(self.wind_pac, width = 20)
    a_materno.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    #Nombre(s)
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Nombre(s)', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 10)
    names = Entry(self.wind_pac, width = 20)
    names.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    #Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_price), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    #Edad
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Edad', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 10)
    edad = Entry(self.wind_pac)
    edad.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

    #Sexo
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Sexo', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 5, column = 1)
    seleccion = IntVar()
    rb_masc = Radiobutton(self.wind_pac, text = 'Masculino', value = 1, variable = seleccion, bg = 'gray').grid(row = 6, column = 1)
    rb_fem = Radiobutton(self.wind_pac, text = 'Femenino', value = 2, variable = seleccion, bg = 'gray').grid(row = 7, column = 1)

    #Fecha de nacimiento a partir de una lista
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Fecha de nacimiento', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 8, column = 1)
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Dia', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 9, column = 1)
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Mes', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 9, column = 2)
    Label(self.wind_pac, text = 'Año', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 9, column = 3)

    dia = Entry(self.wind_pac, width = 5)
    dia.grid(row = 10, column = 1)
    mes = tk.StringVar(self.wind_pac)
    mes.set('--')
    meses = ('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre')
    menu_mes = tk.OptionMenu(self.wind_pac, mes, *meses).grid(row = 10, column = 2)
    year = Entry(self.wind_pac, width = 5)
    year.grid(row = 10, column = 3)


    #tabla     

    # Aniadimos el Treeview (El primer parametro es donde quiero que aparezca dicho Treeview, es decir en el frame que se creo dentro de la Top level)
    self.treecommentab1 = ttk.Treeview(self.wind_pac, height = 10, columns = ('1','2', '3', '4', '5'), style="STTView.Treeview") 
    self.treecommentab1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, ipady = 60)
    self.treecommentab1.grid(row = 12, column = 0, columnspan = 9)
    self.treecommentab1.heading('#0', text = 'Apellido Paterno', anchor = CENTER)
    self.treecommentab1.heading('#1', text = 'Apellido Materno', anchor = CENTER)
    self.treecommentab1.heading('#2', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
    self.treecommentab1.heading('#3', text = 'Edad', anchor = CENTER)
    self.treecommentab1.heading('#4', text = 'Sexo', anchor = CENTER)
    self.treecommentab1.heading('#5', text = 'Fecha de nacimiento', anchor = CENTER)

    self.get_rgpacient()

    #creacion de un boton sobre la otra ventana
    self.aceptar = tk.Button(self.wind_pac, text = 'Cargar paciente', bg = 'gray', command = self.add_pac) 
    self.aceptar.grid(row = 15, column = 1, pady = 30, sticky = W + E)
    self.aceptar = tk.Button(self.wind_pac, text = 'Cerrar', bg = 'gray') 


def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):  #query es consulta 
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_lab) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result     

# Consulta de datos
def get_rgpacient(self):
    #limpiando la tabla
    records = self.treecommentab1.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.treecommentab1.delete(element)
    #consultando datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM pacient_data ORDER BY ap_paterno DESC' 
    db_rows = self.run_query(query) #filas de la base de datos

    #llenando los datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.treecommentab1.insert('', 0, text = row[0], values = (row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))


def validation(self):
   return len(self.a_paterno.get()) !=0 and len(self.a_materno.get()) !=0 and len(self.names.get()) !=0 and len(self.edad.get()) !=0 and len(self.sexo.get()) !=0

def add_pac(self):
    if self.add_pac():
        query = 'INSERT INTO pacient_data VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
        parameters = (self.a_paterno.get(), self.a_materno.get(), self.nombre.get(), self.edad.get(), self.sexo.get())
        self.run_query(query, parameters)

    else:
        print('nombre completro requerido')
    self.get_rdpacient() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
window = Tk()
window.configure(background = 'gray')
application = Product(window)
window.mainloop()
```

De alguna manera pienso que mi problema puede estar en esta parte del codigo que enuncio a continuacion, porque al momento de dar click en mi boton de "cargar paciente" aparece el error de runtimeerror

```
#llenando los datos
  for row in db_rows:
    self.treecommentab1.insert('', 0, text = row[0], values = (row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))

def validation(self):
   return len(self.a_paterno.get()) !=0 and len(self.a_materno.get()) !=0 and len(self.names.get()) !=0 and len(self.edad.get()) !=0 and len(self.sexo.get()) !=0

def add_pac(self):
  if self.add_pac():
    query = 'INSERT INTO pacient_data VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
    parameters = (self.a_paterno.get(), self.a_materno.get(), self.nombre.get(), self.edad.get(), self.sexo.get())
    self.run_query(query, parameters)

  else:
    print('nombre completro requerido')
self.get_rdpacient()
```

espero y puedan ayudarme y si esta un poco largo mi codigo :S

Comment: Hola Johnny, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Qué pretendes exactamente con  el condicional `if self.add_pac()` dentro del propio método `add_pac`? Esto está causando tu problema, el método se llama a si mismo de forma indefinida (recursión) por culpa de este if.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, muchas gracias por la bienvenida, en si lo que quiero en ese condicional es que se carguen los datos de mi paciente por apellido paterno materno, nombre, etc, y se carguen en mi BD de igual forma en mi GUI, de hecho gracias a tu comentario corregi eso, por la linea: if self.validation() se quito la recursion... pero que crees me salio este mensaje

Comment: File "laboratorio.py", line 130, in validation
    return len(self.a_paterno.get()) !=0 and len(self.a_materno.get()) !=0 and len(self.names.get()) !=0 and len(self.edad.get()) !=0 and len(self.sexo.get())
AttributeError: Product instance has no attribute 'a_paterno' entiendo que ya no esta el atributo de a_paterno no?

Comment: Borre la publicación ya que estaba mal de mi parte. En que momento de la ejecución del programa te sale el error del la linea 130?

Comment: Gracias amigo Loki, en el momento de llenar los campos de datos de paciente en apellido paterno materno nombre y edad (para el sexo tengo unos radiobuttons en los cuales tengo que aprender a usarlos los cuales aun no habilito), y presiono mi boton de cargar paciente aparece el error. agradezco tu tiempo amigo loki

Comment: `a_paterno` nunca es definido como un atributo de clase (`a_paterno = Entry(self.wind_pac, width = 20)`), solo es una variable local del método `ventana_paciente` y deja de existir cuando este retorna. Para que sea un atributo de clase y poder accedere desde otro método de instancia debe ser     `self.a_paterno = Entry(self.wind_pac, width = 20)`, lo mismo con `a_materno`, etc

Comment: FJSevilla, ohhh entiendo de hecho hice el cambio y empezo a correr, entonces debo de darle un atributo de clase con self si voy a seguir trabajando con esa variable fuera de los metodos locales verdad???